# Gnuplot for server-side equation

Tags: charts, gnuplot

is it possible to somehow use gnuplot for plotting charts on server-side and throwing an image to frontend? No js, if it's possible.

i tried to use pChart 1.26, but it has problems with rendering big data (~1000-1500 dots) - it's about 30 seconds and mor - maybe because i did it on my local PC.

here's code of what i tried.

```
<?php
include("pChart/pData.class");
include("pChart/pChart.class");
error_reporting(0);

function arr_parser($arr, $par){
    $tmp = array(); 
    foreach ($arr as $dat){
        $tmp[] = $dat[$par];
    }
    return $tmp;
}
function graphPlotter(){

    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('test.json'), true);

    $Data = new pData;
    // $Data->AddPoint(arr_parser($data["Point"], 'x'), "SerieX");
    $Data->AddPoint(arr_parser($data["Point"], 'y'), "SerieY");
    $Data->AddPoint(arr_parser($data["Point"], 'z'), "SerieZ");
    $Data->AddAllSeries();
    $Data->SetAbsciseLabelSerie();
    // $Data->SetSerieName("X","SerieX");
    $Data->SetSerieName("Y","SerieY");
    $Data->SetSerieName("Z","SerieZ");


    $Chart = new pChart(800, 300);
    $Chart->setFontProperties("Fonts/tahoma.ttf",8);
    $Chart->setGraphArea(50,30,750,260);
    $Chart->drawGraphArea(255,255,255,FALSE);
    $Chart->drawGrid(0,FALSE,230,230,230,50);
    $Chart->drawScale($Data->GetData(),$Data->GetDataDescription(),SCALE_NORMAL,150,150,150,TRUE,0,2,TRUE,10);  

    $Chart->setFontProperties("Fonts/tahoma.ttf",6);
    $Chart->drawTreshold(0,143,55,72,TRUE,TRUE);
    $Chart->drawBarGraph($Data->GetData(),$Data->GetDataDescription(),TRUE);

    $Chart->setFontProperties("Fonts/tahoma.ttf",8);
    $Chart->drawLegend(596,144,$Data->GetDataDescription(),255,255,255);
    $Chart->setFontProperties("Fonts/tahoma.ttf",10);
    $Chart->drawTitle(50,22,"Example 12",50,50,50,585);
    $start = microtime(true);
    $Chart->Render("test.png");
}
$start = microtime(true);
graphPlotter();
$time = microtime(true);
echo '<pre>' . ($time-$start) . '</pre>';
?>
```

Maybe it's not well-optimised, but still it's too long.

Gnuplot is probably one free plotting solution left to try. Bt i need it to work on server-side.

Any solution?

Comment: you should clarify a bit your problem. What have you tried?

Comment: @bibi i need to make chart on server side, then i need to send plotted image on client-side. Gnuplot is probably only free solution left to try, but is there any server-side solution of that? I tried pchart 1.26, but it cant handle fast plotting of 1000 dots (maybe because i did it on my local PC) - pchart rendered it in about 40 seconds. This is TOO long, taking in view that fact that it is supposed to be more than one chart.

Comment: What did you do? please post code/config read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Besides this how did you get 40s? `gnuplot -e "set table 'test.dat'; set samples 10000; plot sin(x); unset table; set term png; set out 'test.png'; plot 'test.dat'; set out"` creates a 10000 `.dat` file, rereads it and creates a png (which you can embed in an html without js) in milliseconds

Comment: @bibi edited a question as is should be